# related_results/show equivalent in 1.1 twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm using related_results to show a conversation thread in a website application.

I want to migrate the api version to 1.1 but this function is not implemented.

Somebody know how it do that?

Thank you mates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer from Twitter is that no such feature will make it to API 1.1 :(
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11292

Comment: Thank you Reivax. I try to do a recursive function for get the related_results with in_reply_to_user_id.